# Principled BSDF Menu Problems

Tags: materials

While doing  a tutorial on how to make a Microphone I reached this step:

We will assign a material by using - Principled BSDF

Scroll down to the very bottom and click on  Displacement - Open that menu and choose checkerboard texture.  (Here are  the screen shots from the tutorial)

[image: This is the instructors screen shot]

Here is my screen shot and what happens when I click on that menu

[image: this is what I see in blender]

[image]

We are each using Blender 2.79.   Am I missing an addon perhaps ??
Why are these menu's different ??

Comment: His menu and my menu  are DIFFERENT.   I don't show any  textures.  He has a list of lots of textures.

Comment: The reason that they're different is that you're clicking on a different socket type. In the screenshot of the tutorial it shows possible inputs to the displacement socket (vector), while your screenshot is from the height socket (factor).. Please do yourself a favor and use the node editor, even if the tutorial doesn't. The properties become very crowded and it's hard to see what nodes are connected to each other. In the node editor you would've noticed that the sockets have different types due to their color.

Comment: No I am clicking on displacement just as he did and I don't see any textures listed. But you presented a wonderful view of something I have no understanding of. Thanks so much for showing me what you understand but it is all greek to me.You are no doubt a wonderful teacher but I can't' understand one word of what you are even talking about.  Thanks for the Education !!